# How to set menu items in a fragment toolbar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, toolbar

I have a fragment in my Activity and the fragment has its own toolbar. Like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hId7X.png)

Here is the layout of the fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hometsolutions.space.Fragments.ControlFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/Setup_next_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_setup_next"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/setup_next_recycler" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**I want to add menu on the Setup_next_toolbar. Not on the MainActivity toolBar.**

I did this on the fragment:

on the `onCreate`: `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

then

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.Setup_next_menu, menu);
}
```

but it added the menu on the MainActivity tolbar. How can I set menuItems on the **`Setup_next_toolbar`**?

Comment: you just need to add setHasOptionMenu(true) in onCreateView() of your fragment.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34082236/5722385

Comment: I can't see any answer solving the problem you described. Did you manage to get it working? If so, how?

Answer (score 11):

may be its too late, but just solved the same issue and think you would like to know. all you nee is just set up toolbar for activity

```
  ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

this will trigger `onCreateOptionsMenu` in fragment

Comment: This help me with I called above code in `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated` of my `Fragment`. But thinking what was the exact reason for hidden menu icons.

Answer (score 3):

You can set an ImageView in Toolbar and open a popup menu when ImageView is clicked and them handle the menu items clicks in popup menu.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/overflow_menu"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/overflow_menu"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Inside fragment

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

 //Other stuff  

    ImageView overflowMenuImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.overflow_menu);
    overflowMenuImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_item_id){

                        //Do your thing

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.my_menu);
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: its work. solved my problem. thank you so much. save my times.

Comment: wow, Thank you so much for this answer, found after searching 4 hours

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
  //TODO Add your menu entries here
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: This will work on activity but getMenuInflater() doesn't work on Fragments