# OnCreateOptionsMenu is not called during fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I have a fragment that contains a search menu in the toolbar. when user first time click on navigation item, `Fragment` is added in activity which uses `add` method of `FragmentManager` and then it will be `show`, `hide` or `remove` from fragment container according to the logic.

My problem is when the first time I click on navigation item search menu is displayed in the toolbar but afterwards when I come back to this fragment, sometimes there will be blank toolbar without search menu. How can I solve this?

Here is the main part code of fragment:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

    searchFragmentInstance = this;
    filterManager = new FilterManager();

    //set toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //other code...

    return view;
    }
```

Display search menu in toolbar using this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

  //other code...
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192921/how-to-set-menu-items-in-a-fragment-toolbar/49760607

Comment: your method onCreate (in fragment) include this "  setHasOptionsMenu(true) "?

Comment: Yes it contain that method @droidbaza

Comment: I tried it but not working @Rafsanjani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using adding this code:

```
//this method is called when the hidden state of the fragment is changed
//so when fragment is beign displayed using show method of fragment transaction
//this will be called

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);

    if(!hidden){
        //when fragment is not hidden anymore
        //convert the toolbar into actionbar
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)(((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search));
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
}
```