# How to create a Menu Bottom of this type in Android?

Tags: android, menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgExm.png)I am developing an app in android and I want to implement a menu similar to the image, does anyone have any examples of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely  you should use `Fragment` for each bottom navigation `Item / Tab`. Like `FragmentHome`, `FragmentSearch` and `FragmentSettings`.

To change the `Fragment`, add `NavigationItemSelectedListener` to your `BottomNavigationView` and change `Fragment` as per `MenuItem` selection:

```
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
            findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_item1:
                            selectedFragment = FragmentHome.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_item2:
                            selectedFragment = FragmentSearch.newInstance();
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_item3:
                            selectedFragment = FragmentSettings.newInstance();
                            break;
                    }
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Here is a tutorial about: [BottomNavigationView with multiple Fragments](http://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example/)

Here is an useful link:

1. [Android Toolbar Adding Menu Items for different fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721664/android-toolbar-adding-menu-items-for-different-fragments)

Hope this will help to understand the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer here: [Which view should be used for new Material Design Bottom Navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019986/which-view-should-be-used-for-new-material-design-bottom-navigation)

here is a github project for bottom menu: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SpaceNavigationView](https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View) library to get the Bottom Navigation Bar similar to your required design.

- https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View

Other libraries you can have a look.

- https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation
- https://github.com/sephiroth74/Material-BottomNavigation
- https://github.com/Ashok-Varma/BottomNavigation